# NativeScriptAngular http request error Android 4.2

Tags: java, android, angular, web-services, nativescript

I am making an app in angular nativescript, I am using web services, but when I try to do a http request in Android 4, it throws this error. But when I do it on Android 9, there are no errors and it makes the insert.[image]

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { NativeScriptModule, NativeScriptHttpClientModule, NativeScriptFormsModule } from "@nativescript/angular";
import { NgShadowModule } from 'nativescript-ng-shadow';
import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './components/partials/header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './components/partials/footer/footer.component';
import { IndexComponent } from './components/index/index.component';
import { RegistrarComponent } from './components/registrar/registrar.component';


@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        NativeScriptModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        NativeScriptHttpClientModule,
        NgShadowModule,
        NativeScriptFormsModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        HeaderComponent,
        FooterComponent,
        IndexComponent,
        RegistrarComponent,
    ],
    providers: [],
    schemas: [
        NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
    ]
})
/*
Pass your application module to the bootstrapModule function located in main.ts to start your app
*/
export class AppModule { }
```

service

```
post(url: string, body: Object): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl() + url, JSON.stringify(body), { headers: this.getHeaders() })
        .pipe(catchError(function (error: any) {
            return throwError(error || 'Server error');
        }));
}
```

app.gradle

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 17
    generatedDensities = []
    flavorDimensions "versionCode"
  }
  aaptOptions {
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
  }
}
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: What does the API url look like?

Comment: Error is about SSL protocol. Maybe you are using a ssl certificate which old OS support?

Comment: I use https in Api url, https://example.com.pe/back-app/api

Answer (score 0):

Try to this:- Add **HttpClientModule** In App Module.

```
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { NativeScriptModule, NativeScriptHttpClientModule, 
NativeScriptFormsModule } from "@nativescript/angular";
import { NgShadowModule } from "nativescript-ng-shadow";
import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from 
  './components/partials/header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from 
  './components/partials/footer/footer.component';
import { IndexComponent } from './components/index/index.component';
import { RegistrarComponent } from 
  './components/registrar/registrar.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";

 @NgModule({
 bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
 ],
 imports: [
    NativeScriptModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NativeScriptHttpClientModule,
    NgShadowModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    NativeScriptFormsModule
 ],
 declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    IndexComponent,
    RegistrarComponent,
 ],
 providers: [],
 schemas: [
     NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
 ]
})
/*
Pass your application module to the bootstrapModule function located in 
main.ts to start your app
*/
export class AppModule { }
```

And Add One Line In AndroidManifest.xml File:-

```
<application
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

**File Location:-** App_Resource->Android->src->main